# innerHTML doesn't work correct at SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

With the following script I want to change the content color of the [text]-element (if its not "0") but it just change all [text] or nothing. Whats my fail?

HTML

```
<svg id="list">
  <g><text class="count" x=20 y=50>0</text></g>
  <g><text class="count" x=60 y=50>8</text></g>
  <g><text class="count" x=100 y=50>15</text></g>
</svg>
```

JS

```
$("svg#list").filter(function() {
   return document.getElementsByClassName('.count').innerHTML != '0';
}).css('fill','#ff0000');
```

[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8731rxmk/)

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection so it does not have an innerHTML attribute.

Comment: @csm_dev Hm, ok, so how can I just change one, two aso. classes, like the html way?

Comment: Why not give all the text elements that are not 0 another class? Then just set the class to whatever you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other solution is to use `.each()`, go thought each `.count` under `#list` check if text not equal to `'0'` then update the css.

Problem in your code, `document.getElementsByClassName('.count')` return an array of object, so .innerHTML won't work.

Also `$("svg#list").filter` will only run once since there is only 1 element `#list`.

```js
$('#list .count').each(function(){
  if($(this).text() != '0'){
    $(this).css('fill','#ff0000');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="list">
  <g><text class="count" x=20 y=50>0</text></g>
  <g><text class="count" x=60 y=50>8</text></g>
  <g><text class="count" x=100 y=50>15</text></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you too for you great support and your good statement, this helps!

Comment: This works in my case a bit better, but both of your answers are very helpfull, thx you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `getElementsByClassName` returns a nodeList, so it's `innerHTML` would never be `"0"`. Secondly, why do you filter elements with ID's. ID's are unique, there's only one `#list` element.

What you wanted was probably to filter the `.count` elements based on their inner HTML, and you'd do that like this

```js
$("#list .count").filter(function() {
   return $(this).html().trim() !== "0";
}).css('fill','#ff0000');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="list">
  <g><text class="count" x=20 y=50>0</text></g>
  <g><text class="count" x=60 y=50>8</text></g>
  <g><text class="count" x=100 y=50>15</text></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for support! Interesting informations! I just dont understand what you mean with my ID, I still use it once like you, or not?

Comment: My point being, you do `$("svg#list").filter(function() { ...` but there's only one `svg#list` element, as that ID is unique, so there's nothing to filter.

Comment: Daniel H answer works in my case a bit better, but both of your answers are very helpfull, thx you guys!